# AngularJS REST Api Select box ng-change

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-change

I am loading data into select boxes from external url. The problem is that ng-change is not triggered at all. However, if I create a local array it works!! I would like to update the main url based on the selection.

I noticed however, that the 'value' field of the options are 'undefined', but the select box gets populated with post.site_name.

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="site_name as post.site_name for post in posts"
            ng-model="something" ng-change="updatee(post.path)">
    <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
 .controller('HotelCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader, $timeout, $rootScope, $log ) 
{
 var postsApi = 'http://my_URL';

 $scope.updatee = function(newLink) {
    console.log('works');
    $rootScope.url = newLink;
 };

 $scope.loadPosts = function() {
   DataLoader.get( postsApi ).then(function(response) {
       $scope.posts = response.data;

   }, function(response) {
      $log.error('error', response);     
   });
 }

 $scope.loadPosts();

})
```

And the service:

```
.factory('DataLoader', function( $http, $log ) {
 return {
  get: function(url) {
    // Simple index lookup
    return $http.get( url );
  }
 } 
})
```

I've been at this at least a day now, and going crazy... Appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: Is the select within the <div ng-controller="HotelCtrl"> within your HTML?

Comment: When do you expect the ng-change to be triggered? Won't it only trigger once you select a value? Or is that data not loading in at all?

Comment: Is the issue that the console.log('works') is never called or does the newLink arg to updatee() get passed in as null?

Comment: tried to add <div ng-controller="HotelCtrl"> but that didn't solve it. Also, the updatee() function never got called. The answer below did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this select tag.

```
<select ng-options="post.site_name as post.site_name for post in posts"
        ng-model="something" ng-change="updatee(post.path)">
```

The ng-options syntax is `select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_`

You are passing `label` correctly, but not the `select`. so `post.path` is not properly loaded.

Comment: P.S: Please mark it as answer if it helped you. Thanks